# Regarding the use of an Em Dash in the following sentence

Tags: punctuation

Is the use of the em dash justified in the following sentence?

*Man, who is by nature proud and susceptible to temptation, often acts hastily without using that faculty of his mind which separates him from the animal kingdom—foresight*.

Comment: It's okay but would read better like this: *Man, who is by nature proud and susceptible to temptation, often acts hastily without using foresight—that faculty of his mind which separates him from the animal kingdom.*

Comment: Yes that looks much better. Thank you.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat It reads better the way the author wanted it. But the dash separates appositives, [that faculty of his mind which separates him from the animal kingdom] and [foresight]. Putting the expansion first adds a stylish emphasis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It read awkwardly to me, and the author seemed to agree.

Comment: What's your grammar question?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Ah, I thought OP was quoting. But though the reversed form may probably be analysed (the action) more easily, putting the single word rather than the expansion last is more punchy, and a common (but not over-common) device.

Comment: Since the original question involves whether or not the Em dash is appropriate, I would think that a colon would accomplish the same goal of emphasizing the word "foresight" while also being less jarring to the reader.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree that the punchline should be last. But the set up would need to be finessed: *Man, who is by nature proud and susceptible to temptation, often acts hastily without using that which separates him from the animal kingdom—foresight.*

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat I disagree. It's fine as it is.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I think Tinfoil Hat has it right. After all, there's this _Heavy-NP shift_ rule backing his version (despite it being a fringe concept of linguistics.)

Comment: @user405662 But there's also the 'use an unusual though not ungrammatical word order to emphasise, startle, provoke thought' rule that writers of a certain standard use.